# Python 2.7 : delete item from list by value

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

After performing some operations I get a `list` as following :

```
FreqItemset(items=[u'A_String_0'], freq=303)
FreqItemset(items=[u'A_String_0', u'Another_String_1'], freq=302)
FreqItemset(items=[u'B_String_1', u'A_String_0', u'A_OtherString_1'], freq=301)
```

I'd like to remove from list all items start from **A_String_0** , but I'd like to keep other items (doesn't matter if A_String_0 exists in the middle or at the end of item )

So in example above delete lines 1 and 2 , keep line 3

I tried

```
 filter(lambda a: a != 'A_String_0', result)
```

and

```
result.remove('A_String_0')
```

all this doesn't help me

Comment: The second method works for me.

Comment: What do you mean by *I'd like to remove from list all items start from A_String_0*?

Comment: He wants to remove 'A_String_0' if it's the first element in the list, else leave it alone

Comment: I see function calls,  not lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth

sets = [
    FPGrowth.FreqItemset(
       items=[u'A_String_0'], freq=303),
    FPGrowth.FreqItemset(
        items=[u'A_String_0', u'Another_String_1'], freq=302),
    FPGrowth.FreqItemset(
        items=[u'B_String_1', u'A_String_0', u'A_OtherString_1'], freq=301)
]

[x for x in sets if x.items[0] != 'A_String_0']
## [FreqItemset(items=['B_String_1', 'A_String_0', 'A_OtherString_1'], freq=301)]
```

In practice it would better to filter beffore collect:

```
filtered_sets = (model
    .freqItemsets()
    .filter(lambda x: x.items[0] != 'A_String_0')
    .collect())
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example ? In case I'd like to search for 'A_S*' instead of 'A_String_0' ?

Comment: `x.items[0].startswith("A_S")`

Answer (score 2):

How about `result = result if result[0] != 'A_String_0' else result[1:]`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using a list called **FreqItemset**. However, the name suggests that you should be using a **set**, instead of a **list**.

This way, you could have a set of searchable pairs string, frequency. For example:

```
>>> d = { "the": 2, "a": 3 }
>>> d[ "the" ]
2
>>> d[ "the" ] = 4
>>> d[ "a" ]
3
>>> del d[ "a" ]
>>> d
{'the': 4}
```

You can easily access each word (which is a key of the dictionary), change its value (its frequency of apparition), or remove it. All operations avoid the access to all the elements of the list, since it is a dictionary, i.e., its performance is good (better than using a list, anyway).

Just my two cents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help . I'll try . About the type of Itemset , when I execute "print type (result) " I get a list . ( result = model....)

Comment: Do you mean you cannot change it?

Comment: As I understand it's list of sets

Comment: You should use the most appropriate data structure. If a list of sets does not suit you, then change it to a simple set.